# Reference to Moshiach in Proverbs Chapter 8?

Tags: messiah, mishlei

I've been reading about Moshiach for about a year.  Then the other day, I read the [above 9 lines (Proverbs 8:22-31)](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2808.htm#22).  It seems like Wisdom is saying what people are pouring over Isaiah, etc, looking for clues for.  Where can i find some discussion about this?  You are a totally cool website, even if i don't understand how to work it!

Comment: Could you please elborate a little more as to what you are looking for?

Comment: The verses you mention are talking with the anthropormiphised voice of wisdom and understanding, or Torah and Mitzvot. Can you explain better in your question. *edit the question* why you think it's related to the messiah?

Answer (score 2):

Proverbs 8:1-3 clearly states that what is coming afterwards (including 22-31) is the voice of wisdom and understanding, so it is not a statement about Moshiach, but rather a statement about the value of wisdom.

The two Hebrew words for wisdom and understanding are Chochmah and Binah. [This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28007/chachma-bina-vaadat-whats-the-difference) explores the difference.

Answer (score 1):

[Pirkei Avot 6:10](http://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.6.10) indicates that the discussion is about the Torah, not Mashiach.

> חמשה קנינים קנה לו הקדוש ברוך הוא בעולמו; 
>   ואלו הן: תורה קנין אחד... 
>   תורה מנין, דכתיב: ה' קנני ראשית דרכו קדם מפעליו מאז..

Comment: Are you referring to what the Sefaria website has listed as [Pirkei Avot 6:10](http://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.6.10)?

Comment: Yes. Apparently it should be 6:10, not 6:11. I'll correct it accordingly.